# How can I use a dynamic number for new Array(integer)?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that creates a new array with a given number of elements. How can I change the static number to a dynamic number based on the value of an external variable?

For example, if gameMode = 'easy', I would like 4 elements. If gameMode = 'Medium', I would like 6 elements. If gameMode = 'hard', I would like 8 elements.

Here are the lines of code I would like to ammend:

```
const ammoCards = [...Array(4)].map(i => new Card('ammunition', 'img/react.svg', null, 1).createCards())
const beerCards = [...Array(4)].map(i => new Card('beer', 'img/angular.svg', 1, null).createCards())
const cigarCards = [...Array(2)].map(i => new Card('cigar', 'img/ember.svg', 1, null).createCards())
```

Comment: Turn your pseudo-code into real code... `let number; if (gameMode == 'easy') number = 4; if (gameMode == 'Hard') number = 6;`

Comment: Why do you need it to be a fixed size?

Comment: Thanks Phil. I just updated the question to be more specific. There are many different cards being created and each will have its own amound depending on difficulty. I understand what you are saying but I am wondering if there is a way to do this without have to create a ton of extra variables.

Comment: Chevybow, I want a certain amount of each type of card to be loaded based on the game difficulty. I updated the code so you could see a couple of the other cards being generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have `Map<gameMode, amountControls>` and use that when creating your data:

```js
const gameModeToAmounts = new Map([
  ['easy', { ammo: 4, beer: 4, cigar: 2 }],
  ['medium', { ammo: 6, beer: 6, cigar: 2 }],
  ['hard', { ammo: 8, beer: 8, cigar: 2 }]
])

const gameMode = 'medium';
const amounts = gameModeToAmounts.get(gameMode);

const ammoCards = [...Array(amounts.ammo)].map(i => new Card('ammunition', 'img/react.svg', null, 1).createCards())
const beerCards = [...Array(amounts.beer)].map(i => new Card('beer', 'img/angular.svg', 1, null).createCards())
const cigarCards = [...Array(amounts.cigar)].map(i => new Card('cigar', 'img/ember.svg', 1, null).createCards())
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I may have updated the code after you were working on your response. If you notice now. Each different type of card will require an independent number so having 3 fixed numbers will not work.

Comment: @gumball I see. I edited my answer with the adjustment.

Comment: See also [`Array.prototype.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) as an alternative to `map()`

Answer (score 1):

Define the config for each game mode:

```
const GAME_MODE = {
    EASY: { ammo: 42, beer: 4, cigars: 1 },
    MEDIUM: { ammo: 6, beer: 4, cigars: 2 },
    HARD: { ammo: 8, beer: 4, cigars: 2 }
}
```

Then create the arrays based on the current game mode config:

```
const currentGameMode = 'EASY'
const currentCOnfig = GAME_MODE[currentGameMode]

const ammoCards = [...Array(currentConfig.ammo)].map(i => new Card('ammunition', 'img/react.svg', null, 1).createCards())
const beerCards = [...Array(currentConfig.beer)].map(i => new Card('beer', 'img/angular.svg', 1, null).createCards())
const cigarCards = [...Array(currentConfig.cigar)].map(i => new Card('cigar', 'img/ember.svg', 1, null).createCards())
```